# Add columns into grid using dynamic sql query

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

How do I add columns into grid with the help of dynamic sql query.The column names come from the database.

**My code is:**

```
select Exam_Name from tbl_Exam_Type.
```

In this Exam_Name can be: 
Unit-1,Unit-2,Quarterly etc...

**OutPut:**

```
    Unit-1   Unit-2   Quarterly 
     69       73        85           like that
```

Answer (score 1):

For a `GridView` control, you use the `AutoGenerateColumns` attribute set to `true` in your `GridView` markup, like this:

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

This will make a column for every field returned by your binding query with the exact name used in the query.